# Mocks not getting invoked with static members using PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I am trying to mock an Impl that contains 2 static members A, B, and a static method Utils.SomeMethod. I tried to mix PowerMock and Mockito initially but was not sure if this was causing the problem so I changed all refs to PowerMockito. I get unit test failures that mocks are not getting invoked. if I remove statics and just use Mockito then all tests succeed.

Here is a brief outline of the problem.

```
class Impl {

static A a;

static B b;

private static final String s = Utils.SomeMethod();

void mainMethod() {

   a.aMethod("foo");
   b.bMethod("bar");

}

}
```

So in my unit test I have

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.net.ssl.*" , "javax.crypto.*"})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Utils.class})
public class ImplTest {

  A a;
  B b;
  @Captor
  ArgumentCaptor<String> argumentCaptor;

  @BeforeClass
  static public void setUp() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Utils.class);
    PowerMockito.when(Utils.SomeMethod()).thenReturn("test"); // works
  }

  @Before
  public void before() {
    a = PowerMockito.mock(A.class);
    b = PowerMockito.mock(B.class);
    impl = PowerMockito.mock(Impl.class);
    impl.setA(a); // I tried @Mock and @InjectMocks but seemed to not work on statics, works with non static members
    impl.setB(b);
 }

   @Test
   public void test() {
      PowerMockito.when(a
        .aMethod(any(String.class))
        .thenReturn("hmm");

    PowerMockito.when(b.bMethod(any(String.class))
        .thenReturn("yo");

     impl.mainMethod();

    verify(a, times(1)).aMethod(argumentCaptor.capture());
    // fails that 0 times mock was invoked 
   }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see it you are mocking `Impl` but you should instantiate it if you want mainMethod invoke your static methods.
Also, are you initializing argumentCaptor somewhere in your code?

Comment: You're right and partially that mistake happened because I always used `@InjectMock` and `@Mock` annotations.  Few questions 1. Can I use this with static members? In my testing it does not work. 2. Is there any better way than setting it or a getter method like getA(), and then mock getA() and then I use getA() in Impl to refer A. 3. Could I mix Mockito and PowerMockito `when`.

Comment: 1. I think you should, why do you say it's not working?
2. Check out Andrew S answer's here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48691837/how-do-i-mock-a-private-field-using-powermockito seems to be a similar scenario

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest using Mockito for most testing mocks, and using PowerMockito only when dealing with some static methods. With slight changes, your test code worked ok:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ Utils.class })
public class ImplTest {

    @Mock
    A a;

    @Mock
    B b;

    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<String> argumentCaptor;

    @BeforeClass
    static public void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Utils.class);
        Mockito.when(Utils.SomeMethod()).thenReturn("test"); // works
    }

    Impl impl;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        Impl.setA(a);
        Impl.setB(b);

        impl = new Impl();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
       Mockito
            .when(a.aMethod(Matchers.any(String.class)))
            .thenReturn("hmmm");

       Mockito
            .when(b.bMethod(Matchers.any(String.class)))
            .thenReturn("yo");

      impl.mainMethod();

      Mockito.verify(a, Mockito.times(1)).aMethod(argumentCaptor.capture());
      Assert.assertEquals("foo", argumentCaptor.getValue());

      Mockito.verify(b, Mockito.times(1)).bMethod(argumentCaptor.capture());
      Assert.assertEquals("bar", argumentCaptor.getValue());
    }

}
```

Please notice that if A and B are defined as static, they should be injected into the class, not into individual instance(s).

`@InjectMocks` will not work in this context, since it requires a different Runner. Please have a look at this other article [Difference between @Mock and @InjectMocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467685/difference-between-mock-and-injectmocks)